# Is there an omniauth for php?

Tags: php, authentication, omniauth

Omniauth is a wrapper that standardizes authentication with multiple third-party providers for Ruby on Rails applications.

For more information, see
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/

Is there a similar library that does this for PHP web applications?

Comment: PHP League has some oauth packages: http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/index.html) is one of the choices.

Comment: I'm still open to other suggestions as well

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Opauth](http://opauth.org). It's an OmniAuth-inspired authentication framework for PHP.

It allows developer to easily implement authentication to 3rd party providers simply by downloading and dropping strategies.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Opauth.

Comment: If you're advertising your own library you should always add a disclaimer to your post! IMHO, opauth is a great idea but so far the implementation is quite lacking.

Comment: Thanks @markus-tharkun for editing and adding that in for me.

Answer (score 0):

This [PHP oAuth API library](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html) comes with built-in support to integrate many oAuth servers, but it can be configured to access any other server that is not yet supported built-in. It supports either oAuth 1.0, 1.0a and 2.0 transparently under the same class API.

Answer (score -2):

Look into [OpenID](http://openid.net/), I am not familiar with the framework you're asking about but it seems to do what you are asking. The Stack Exchange network implemented it too, which is how we can login using Google accounts etc.

Comment: omniauth does provide openid authentication, which is used by google, but facebook login is not openid, I'd like to know if there's a library that provides openid and more.

Comment: Sorry for not knowing you wanted facebook authentication - Perhaps you should edit your question to include an actual list of third party providers you want. As is, OpenID fit your question.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding what my comment is about. It's not about having it in facebook (I could care less about facebook, I'm using it as an example), it's about having a library that provides third party authentication to almost every major service that provides one. Look at omniauth and you'll see what I mean, omniauth is awesome! :)